# Fire base Dynamic link

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have Question about that function

I'm using Xamarin.android

when I open the url the app open that's fine but
my task is I'm making reset password form at the app I will send the url to the user at the email address and when the user click at the link open the specific page(reset_password form)

that what I used at my manifest

```
  <activity android:name="com.companyname.petrol_stations_in_egypt">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSEABLE"/>
     <data android:host="publicservices.page.link/resetpassword" android:scheme="https"/>
     <data android:host="publicservices.page.link/resetpassword" android:scheme="http"/>
     </intent-filter>
  </activity>
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

I have created my own solve but I ask if there is another way thanks :)
when I open the app for 1st time it will pass this code

```
if (Intent.DataString == "https://publicservices.page.link/resetpassword")
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Reset_Password));
    StartActivity(intent);
}
```

and when the user click the url link it will get at the intent datastring the url path so I put if condition and I will pass to the other form

Comment: You can mark your answer which will help more people with same problem:).